# How do client-side web-based agents work?

Tags: http, agent

I'm not sure if I'm asking the question properly. I'm referring to locally installed software, often called an "Agent" that keeps in regular communication with some host via HTTP.  e.g.  When you install LogMeIn, the Agent keeps in communication with the logmein.com server so that when you visit logmein.com with your web browser and connect to the agent, the server is able to initiate communication.  The Agent, however, isn't a webserver, nor are any ports forwarded to the Agent.  So, is the Agent constantly polling the server asking like a broken record, "Can I help you?  Can I help you?  Can I help you?"  Or is the http connection from Agent to server somehow kept open?  I know you can keep an http connection open, but A) how, and B) for how long?  Does the Agent need to act like a less annoying broken record asking, "Can I help you?  Yet?  Yet?  Yet?"  with much more time in between each question?  Or can the Agent ask once and wait indefinitely, asking again only once it learns that the connection has been dropped?

Bottom line is, I'd like to create a small little sample program for trying my hand at writing a client/server application that communicates via the Internet using HTTP.  Either side needs to be able to initiate commands / requests.  The Agent would likely communicate with the Server using some sort of API, perhaps RESTful.  When I start the experiment, I'll be using Perl.  It'd be fun to create a Hello World project that would have samples in many languages for many platforms how to write the agent and how to communicate with the server.  The agent code would do client side things (e.g. determine public IP address) and send the data to the server.  The server would act on the data (e.g. store IP address in a database).  The server might also initiate a command to the Agent (e.g. Hey, Agent!  What's your CPU type?)  Proper authentication / authorization between Agent and Server is of course a necessity.

Are there any existing projects to model off of?  Any existing documents?  Perhaps I'm just missing terminology and if I just knew that everything I was asking can be summarized by the term foo, then the doors would be opened wide for what I could find in searches!

Comment: Try http://windowssecrets.com/top-story/run-your-pc-from-afar-securely-and-easily/ and http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1598113.

Logmein uses port 80 and 443 btw!

Comment: On Windows, LogMeIn is a windows service. I'm not sure how it communicates since I haven't used it in a long time. I have used Dropbox, and it just asks the server every so often if there is anything to sync. You can see this communication if you install Fiddler.

Answer (score 1):

I looked into the code of Ubuntu's Landscape.  It uses Python's Twister -- a web server for HTML5 Websockets.  So I'd say what I was looking for in an answer is Websockets (bi-directional communication).  That now has opened up a wealth of options, node.js, twister, mojolicious, and many many more as web servers.  Turns out using Ajax to poll every few seconds is a very bad idea -- an overwhelming slam on web servers.  Keep the connection open.